# How can I yank (copy) the single character on which the cursor rests?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I know many ways to copy things:

`yiw` = yank in current word
`yaw` = yank all word (includes a trailing space)
`yy`  = yank the current line
`3yy` = yank three lines starting at the current one
`yap` = yank all paragraph (includes trailing newline)

I can also delete or change a single character:

`x` = delete the character under the cursor
`r` = replace the character under the cursor

But how in the world do you simply copy a single character under the cursor?

My motivation is that I'm programming in Perl 6 and some of the operators are Unicode characters. Right now I'm using [tadzik's Perl 6 Config::INI code](https://github.com/tadzik/perl6-Config-INI/blob/master/lib/Config/INI.pm) as a starting point for a custom parser, for example, and I would have liked to have copied just that one [French quote character (a hyper operator)](https://doc.perl6.org/language/operators#postfix_%C2%BB._%2F_postfix_%3E%3E.) from [this line](https://github.com/tadzik/perl6-Config-INI/blob/master/lib/Config/INI.pm#L26):

```
my %hash = $<sections>».ast;
```

I could use the two character "Texas" version of the hyper operator `>>`, but I thought that `>»` looked better and less ambiguous than `>>>`:

```
my %hash = $<sections>>>.ast;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Easily, compose the operation with the motion, as usual: `yl`

Comment: @VanLaser Good idea! I was thinking that movement wouldn't work because I only wanted that one character. But your suggestion works great for ASCII. Post that as an answer and I'll vote it up. Interestingly it doesn't work with this Unicode character, but `ytX` ("`y`ank `t`il `X`") seems to work when `X` is the character just to the right.

Comment: I wonder, is that one character, be it Unicode, or aren't there two characters, hidden/replaced using Vim `conceal` feature?

Comment: @VanLaser Seems like two "characters".

Comment: BTW, how do you introduce the `»` character?

Comment: Rather than yutting (that ought to be a standard abbreviation for yank-put, but by saying so I've made this a whole lot longer) the character you can type (in insert mode) `<C-K>>>`. This uses digraphs to insert the `»` character. It's probably faster than exiting insert mode, navigating to the character, yanking it, navigating back, and putting.

Comment: On my keyboard layout I can use the `AltGr``>` combo to insert that character. I was asking more to check the remote possibility that the un-yank-able  `»` was a conceal character for a `>>` sequence.

Comment: @VanLaser Thank you for spelling that out! Using vim for years and always knew the normal `f`  "f ind" command from the start; took me a good while to stumble on `t` ("t ill") but until your comment i never thought about it meaning "t ill" (or I guess it could also mean "t o"). (We differ on our spelling of till but that's here nor there.)

Comment: @Zhora Yes, it should be `till`. I can't edit an old comment, unfortunately.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Composing the yank operation with the so often used "one character to the right" motion should work: `yl`.

BTW (to comment on a OP comment), for me `»` can be yanked in this manner, in gVim or terminal Vim. Perhaps a (file)encoding issue?

Comment: Yanking `»` works fine for me too. I use `vy` to yank a single character. Not sure why I use that rather than `yl`, maybe I had a conscious reason once but now it's just reflex.

Comment: I've always done `y<space>` thinking it was yank the character under the cursor, and I was going to add it as an answer but after checking the help I realize `<space>` and `l` are the same thing.

Comment: That's nice, and seemingly even easier to hit, except perhaps when the space is used as leader.

Answer (score 23):

Usually I press `vy` (*visual yank*), sometimes `xu` (*delete undo*) too. Also , if you want to yank the char before your cursor, instead of `lvy`, you can press `Xu`, I think that's the reason why I press `xu` for the current. :-)

Note that, `Xu` will make your cursor move to that char.

Comment: You mean `hvy`. I tried to edit it, but apparently correcting one character in a vim command is not a significant change to be acceptable.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way I know to do this is to use `x` to delete the character, which also puts it in the buffer, and then `P` to put it back.  You can then move the cursor around and paste the character back wherever you want it with `p` (after cursor) or `P` (before cursor), as long as you do not change the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yl` or `yv` to copy a character which is on the cursor.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I think the second one should be `vy`, but I'm not sure this answer adds much value over the existing ones...

Comment: Thanks, `vy` or `yv` both OK for me.

Comment: @meteorsh Welcome to our site. We usually value answers which make an effort to explain things clearly for the readers. Here i would be useful to explain how your solution is different from the already existing answers and why it specifically answers OP question. Usually answers which are not more than a sentence long are considered as low quality.

Comment: Sorry, I am a new starter to use this website and may not know the rules. So I will try to improve my answers next time.